# iOS9 -[__NSArrayM removeAllObjects] Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

Fabric found that the `NSMutableArray` found crash when calling `removeAllObjects`.
Most of the crash happened in iOS9. This is my code, crash in `[self.recommentGoodsArray removeAllObjects]`:

```
- (void)clickColorWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [self.recommentGoodsArray removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    GoodsInfo *gInfo = [self.goodsInfo.relatedGoodsArray objectAt:index];
    self.goods_id = gInfo.goods_id;

    [self loadGoodsDetail];
}
```

Fabric Latest Session

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x22d2a94e realizeClass(objc_class*) + 25
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x22d2aa15 realizeClass(objc_class*) + 224
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x22d2aa15 realizeClass(objc_class*) + 224
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x22d2d91b lookUpImpOrForward + 158
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x22d2d873 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 34
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x22d33cfb _objc_msgSend_uncached + 26
6  CoreFoundation                 0x2357e523 -[__NSArrayM removeAllObjects] + 266
7  ZZKKO                          0x19f781 -[GoodsDetailVC clickColorWithIndex:] (GoodsDetailVC.m:825)
```

[image]

Comment: iPad                50%
iPhone            43%
iPod touch      7%
Operating Systems
9                     98%
11                   2%

Comment: @S. Dew, and your point is?

Comment: You must assign a `NSArray` object to `recommentGoodsArray` somewhere, write a setter method to debug it.

Comment: If I assign a ```NSArray``` object to ```recommentGoodsArray``` somewhere, why only crash on iOS 9.

Comment: Make sure you are not using the same array from another thread at the same time, e.g. from a request.

Answer (score 1):

You have a crash in `_objc_msgSend_uncached`. It's likely that you are addressing deallocated object.  It cat either be `recommentGoodsArray`, or `self`.

You need to check following:

1. Is recommentGoodsArray declared `strong` or `weak`? It has to be
   `strong`.
2. Is it possible for this method to be called after VC was destroyed (example: from a timer or in a callback from an UIAlertView). If so, you have to retain self until the moment your function is done working with self.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *recommentGoodsArray;
- (NSMutableArray *)recommentGoodsArray { if (!_recommentGoodsArray) { _recommentGoodsArray = [NSMutableArray array]; } return _recommentGoodsArray; }

Comment: Seems like `recommentGoodsArray` is okay. Meaning that it's `self` that gets deallocated. Somewhere in your code there is a week reference to `GoodsDetailVC`. And there is code invoking `clickColorWithIndex`. You have to search through your code. It will probably happen if this method is used in timer, notification observer, delegate.

Comment: That wouldn't happen with `weak` array.

Answer (score -2):

You can try if self.recommentGoodsArray has objects before removing it.

```
if ([self.recommentGoodsArray count]){
   [self.recommentGoodsArray removeAllObjects];
}
```

Comment: Why sometimes removeAllObjects crash when self.recommentGoodsArray.count = 0

Comment: How do you declare the property of self.recommetGoodsArray? See if this explains your question

https://tiwarisudhir.wordpress.com/2014/12/27/nsmutablearray-removeallobjects-crash/

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *recommentGoodsArray;

Comment: - (NSMutableArray *)recommentGoodsArray
{
    if (!_recommentGoodsArray) {
        _recommentGoodsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return _recommentGoodsArray;
}